# Combine each element of a vector with another vector in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I have two vectors

```
x <- c(2, 3, 4)
y <- rep(0, 5)
```

I want to get the following output:

```
> z
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

How can I create `z`? I have tried to use `paste` and `c` but nothing seems to work. The only thing I can think of is using a `for()` and it is terribly slow. I have googled this and I am sure the solution is  out there and I am just not hitting the right keywords.

UPDATE:
For benchmarking purposes:

Using Nicola's solution:

```
 > system.time(
+ precipitation <- `[<-`(numeric(length(x)*(length(y)+1)),seq(1,by=length(y)+1,length.out=length(x)),x)
+ )
user  system elapsed 
0.419   0.407   0.827
```

This is ridiculously fast! I must say! Can someone please explain this to me? My `for()` which I know is always wrong in `R` would have taken at least a day if it even finished.

The other suggestions:

```
 > length(prate)
[1] 4914594
> length(empty)
[1] 207
> system.time(
+ precipitation <- unlist(sapply(prate, FUN = function(prate) c(prate,empty), simplify=FALSE))
+ )
user  system elapsed 
16.470   3.859  28.904
```

I had to kill

```
len <- length(prate)
precip2 <- c(rbind(prate, matrix(rep(empty, len), ncol = len)))
```

After 15 minutes.

Comment: Though not as fast as @nicola's another option is `rep(x, each=length(y)+1)*c(1,y)`

Comment: I made an edit to speed up things when `y` is made of all zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this

```
unlist(sapply(x, FUN = function(x) c(x,y), simplify=FALSE))
 [1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

or simpler from @docendodiscimus

```
unlist(lapply(x, FUN = function(x) c(x,y)))
```

Comment: You could use `lapply` so you don't need to specify simplify = FALSE

Comment: I haven't tried the other suggestions but this is extremely fast (takes appropriately 30 seconds vs. my loop which would have taken at least a day).

Comment: @cddesjardins it would be interesting if you would test the other answers for speed too.

Comment: and you can add y to the call, so it does not rely on y being the name of the second vector, resulting in:

    unlist (lapply(x, function(x, y) c(x,y), y))

Answer (score 5):

This seems faster for some reason:

```
 unlist(t(matrix(c(as.list(x),rep(list(y),length(x))),ncol=2)))
```

The above solution is general, in the sense that both `x` and `y` can have any value. In the OP case, where `y` is made just of 0, this is fast as it can be:

```
 `[<-`(numeric(length(x)*(length(y)+1)),seq(1,by=length(y)+1,length.out=length(x)),x)
 #[1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Edit**

I realise I've been very cryptic and the code I produced is not easy to follow, despite being just one line. I'm gonna explain in detail what the second solution does.

First of all, you notice that the resulting vector will have the values containd in `x` plus the zeroes in `y` repeated `length(x)` times. So in total, it will be `length(x) + length(x)*length(y)` or `length(x)*(length(y)+1)` long. So we create a vector with just zeroes as long as needed:

```
  res<-numeric(length(x)*(length(y)+1))
```

Now we have to place the `x` values in `res`. We notice that the first value of `x` occupies the first value in `res`; the second will be after `length(y)+1` from the first and so on, until all the `length(x)` values are filled. We can create a vector of indices in which to put the `x` values:

```
  indices<-seq.int(1,by=length(y)+1,length.out=length(x))
```

And then we make the replacement:

```
  res[indices]<-x
```

My line was just a shortcut for the three lines above. Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: Your solution is the fastest so far.  I thought the `t` might reduce the speed, but it didn't

Comment: Very nice solution. You can use `integer` instead of `numeric` to make it even faster.

Comment: Also `seq.int` instead of `seq` seems to be faster. ;)

Comment: Can someone please explain this one to me? Also, can someone suggest a place to read, or a book, for learning how to program in R so efficiently?

Comment: nicola's solution is basically short-hand for `x=1:1e5;y=rep(0,40);tmp=numeric(length(x)*(length(y)+1));tmp[seq(1,by=length(y)+1,length.out=length(x))]=x;`. Compare: <code>all.equal(`[<-`(numeric(length(x)*(length(y)+1)),seq(1,by=length(y)+1,length.out=length(x)),x),tmp)</code>

Comment: Damn - wanted to get the back tick in the code in my last comment right and then the 5min max edit time for comments was over. :(

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to vectorize as follows

```
len <- length(x)
c(rbind(x, matrix(rep(y, len), ncol = len)))
## [1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

A more compact, but potentially slower option (contributed by @akrun) would be

```
c(rbind(x, replicate(len, y)))
## [1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Tried some benchmarks on a 1e6 'x' vector and 'y' of length 100.  Using `dim<-` is a bit more faster, @Mamoun Benghezal's solution came up first, the `replicate` solution is the slowest, though on a scale of 1 vs. 2.9

Comment: @akrun Interesting. Strange though

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 c(sapply(x, 'c', y))
 #[1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
```

Or a crazy solution with gusb and paste..

```
library(functional)
p = Curry(paste0, collapse='')

as.numeric(strsplit(p(gsub('(.*)$', paste0('\\1',p(y)),x)),'')[[1]])
#[1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
options(scipen=100)
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x * 10^5), "")))
```

And some benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark({as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x*10^5), "")))}, {unlist(t(matrix(c(as.list(x),rep(list(y),length(x))),ncol=2)))}, {unlist(sapply(x, FUN = function(x) c(x,y), simplify=FALSE))}, times=100000)
Unit: microseconds
                                                                        expr
            {     as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x * 10^5), ""))) }
 {     unlist(t(matrix(c(as.list(x), rep(list(y), length(x))), ncol = 2))) }
      {     unlist(sapply(x, FUN = function(x) c(x, y), simplify = FALSE)) }
   min     lq     mean median     uq       max  neval
 9.286 10.644 12.15242 11.678 12.286  1650.133 100000
 9.485 11.164 13.25424 12.288 13.067  1887.761 100000
 5.607  7.429  9.21015  8.147  8.784 30457.994 100000
```

And here's another idea (but it seems slow):

```
r = rle(1)
r$lengths = rep(c(1,5), length(x))
r$values =  as.vector(rbind(x, 0))
inverse.rle(r)
```

Comment: Based on the `x` from OP's post, I get `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x * 10^5), "")))
 #[1]  2 NA NA  0  5  3 NA NA  0  5  4 NA NA  0  5` which is not the expected result

Comment: Funny, I get the right thing: `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x * 10^5), "")))
 [1] 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: @akrun oh yeah -- turn off scientific notation:  `options(scipen=100)`